# How to write a letter that matches the first letter of the image that is found on the screen

Tags: python, list, pyautogui

I have a list of images:

```
    def justAnObserver():
        kk = 0
        listOfLetterImages = ['A.png','B.png','C.png','D.png','E.png','F.png','G.png','H.png','I.png','J.png','K.png','L.png','M.png','N.    png','O.png','P.png','Q.png','R.png','S.png','T.png','U.png','V.png','W.png','X.png','Y.png','Z.png']

        while True:
            while True:
                for x in listOfLetterImages:
                    try:
                        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(x, region=(350,337,98,103)) is not None:
                        print("jest")
                        kk = 1
                        break
                except Exception:
                    continue
            if kk == 1:
                kk=0
                break
            else:
                continue
```

And I want to, for example, press A on keyboard if A was found, or type R if R was found.

Comment: If you do `for n,x in enumerate(listOfLetterImages):`, then `n` will give you the index of the letter.  0 is A, 1 is B, etc.

Comment: whenever you have something shaped like nested `while True:`, consider a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply search `pyautogui press key` will get what you want. See [Keyboard Control Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

`x` is the filename, `x[0]` gets the first char of the filename (for example, `A`), and `.lower()` convert it to lowercase for `press` function.

```py
    def justAnObserver():
        kk = 0
        listOfLetterImages = ['A.png','B.png','C.png','D.png','E.png','F.png','G.png','H.png','I.png','J.png','K.png','L.png','M.png','N.    png','O.png','P.png','Q.png','R.png','S.png','T.png','U.png','V.png','W.png','X.png','Y.png','Z.png']

        while True:
            while True:
                for x in listOfLetterImages:
                    try:
                        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(x, region=(350,337,98,103)) is not None:
                            pyautogui.press(x[0].lower())  # Here!
                            kk = 1
                            break
                except Exception:
                    continue
            if kk == 1:
                kk=0
                break
            else:
                continue
```

In addition, your code can be rewritten to this for readablility:

```py
import string


def justAnObserver():
    listOfLetterImages = [i+".png" for i in string.ascii_uppercase]

    while True:
        for x in listOfLetterImages:
            try:
                if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(x, region=(350,337,98,103)) is not None:
                    pyautogui.press(x[0].lower())  # Here!
                    return
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: I meant press A on a keyboard, sorry.